# 500 Socket clients trying to push data to my socket server. Need help in handling

Tags: c#, sockets

I am required to create a high performance application where I will be getting 500 socket messages from my socket clients simultaneously. Based on my logs i could see that my dual core system is processing 80 messages at a time.

I am using Async sockets (.BeginRecieve) and i have set NoDelay to true

From the logs from my clients and my server i could see that the message i wrote from my client is read by my server after 3-4 sec.

My service time of my application should be lot lesser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should post your current code so any potential bugs can be identified.

Second, if you're on .NET 3.5, you might want to look at the [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968780.aspx) enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

Start looking at your resource usages:

- CPU usage - both on the overall system, as well as your specific process.
- Memory usage - same as above.
- Networking statistics.

Once you identify where the bottleneck is, both the community and yourself will have an easier time looking at what to focus on next in improving the performance.

A review of your code may also be necessary - but this may be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a [socket.listen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen.aspx), what is your backlog set to?  I can't speak to .net 4.0, but with 2.0 I have seen a problem where once your backlog is filled up (too many connection attempts too fast) then some of the sockets will get a TCP accept and then a TCP Reset.  The Client then may or may not attempt to reconnect later again.  This causes a connection bottleneck rather than a data throughput or a processing bottleneck.